# Adding new line when select with concat

Tags: oracle, plsql

I want to test user passwords so I have created this simple select by using concat :

```
select 'conn '||oracle_username||'/test11@dev;'
from FND_ORACLE_USERID 
where oracle_username not in ('APPS','APPLSYS')
and READ_ONLY_FLAG='A'
;
```

Query results output is like this:

```
conn ALR/test11@dev;
conn AX/test11@dev;
conn AK/test11@dev;
```

And I would like to add one more line under each, to look like this:

```
conn ALR/test11@dev;
disc;
conn AX/test11@dev;
disc;
conn AK/test11@dev;
disc;
```

How to manage this?

Thank you

Comment: You don't need `disconnect` before next `connect` in sqlplus. It doesn't support multiple connections so it will close previous one anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to say

```
select 'conn '||oracle_username||'/test11@dev;' || chr(10) || 'disc;'
  from FND_ORACLE_USERID 
 where oracle_username not in ('APPS','APPLSYS')
   and READ_ONLY_FLAG='A';
```

This will print output for each record in 2 lines

PS. Sometimes it might be needed not only "|| chr(10) ||" but "|| chr(10) || chr(13) ||". Try both if first one does not work.

For me as far as I can remember "chr(10)" worked in both windows and unix

Comment: That worked, i have tried this using Sql developer where it doesn't, so i have executed this in sqlplus and output is fine now. Thanks!

Comment: Why didn't you upvote/accept the answer, then, @user3391373?